# Reorder text file lines by a specific form with awk or somethig simpler #scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

This is the output which is what is inside ezzayak.lst and the result of sqlplus spool

*/Moods*

```
                                                                   مش تمام
     1

                                                                   تمام جدا
     3

                                                                    مش كويس
     2

                                                                      يعني
     3

                                                                      كويس
     7
```

The required output

```
                      */Moods*

     1                 مش تمام
     

     3                 تمام جدا
     

     2                  مش كويس
    

     3                      يعني
     

     7                      كويس
```

sum      16

What I tried was this
export body=$(awk '!/^$/' /usr/home/appsupp/EZZAYAK_MOODS/ezzayak.lst  | awk  '{print $3 " " $1,$2 }')

It gave me this
*/Moods*' مش تمام 1 تمام جدا 3 مش كويس 2 يعني 3 كويس 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat ezzayak.lst  | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " ;}  { if ($1 ~  /^[0-9]+$/ )  { print $1 > 
 "test1"  ;} else { if ($1 != "") {print $1 > "test2"; } }     }  '  ;
 pr -m -t -s  test1 test2 | awk '{ print $1,  $2 ; }' >  reorder.txt
```